# How to setup one ethernet interface as dhcp server and another interface as static ip?

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, installation, networking, 11.10

I am getting a static ip from provider. But in my Ubuntu 11.04 pc i have two reserved ethernet interface mostly both are like getting automatic dhcp IP as of now.

But i want my Ethernet interface 0 as static ip WAN. And Ethernet interface 1 as dhcp server.

How can i do this setup?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to do 'internet connection sharing' with this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work this way: setup the two interfaces in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Install `dhcp3-server` package. After that, in the `/etc/defaults/dhcp3-server` configuration file, you can tell the DHCP server, on what interface(s) it should listen: `INTERFACES="eth0"`. That's all!

Answer (score -1):

Never tried to use both at the same time. I don't know if this is going to work...

but you can try this:

```
sudo -i
vi /etc/network/interfaces
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

It's the first thing It came out from my head.

Comment: Don't you need `sudo` privileges to do 90% of that?

Comment: I assume you're going to do sudo -i

Comment: Never assume anything - always specify something that you need done.

Comment: you are right ... my mistake

Comment: The OP wants a DHCP-Server, not a client!